# OSX Fuerte rosdep install -a fails on pcl

Tags: pcl, rosdep, catkin, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the Homebew OSX instruction till the rosdep install -a line.  Everything worked pretty well and many of the rosdep packages are successful.  But when it gets to pcl, it all fails and I can't figure out how to get around the errors.  This is the output:

executing command [brew install ros/fuerte/pcl]
==> Installing pcl dependency: catkin
Unsatisfied dependency: EmPy
Homebrew does not provide Python dependencies; install with:
easy_install EmPy
==> Cloning git://github.com/wg-debs/catkin.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/catkin--git
fatal: remote error:
Repository not found.
Error: Failure while executing: git fetch -q origin
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
homebrew: command [brew install ros/fuerte/pcl] failed

Even after I install EmPy using pip or easy_install, brew install catkin still fails to find that dependency.
And I have no idea why the git repo of catkin is failing.

Any help would be awesome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36130/osx-fuerte-rosdep-install--a-fails-on-pcl/) by [ecegrad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2582/ecegrad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ecegrad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2582/ecegrad/) on 2012-06-21**:
I can comment out the offending EmPy dependency, but catkin still fails on the git fetch.  Not sure what to do about that.  I had similar problems in Electric with certain rviz dependencies not installing due to missing repos or similar.  I was hoping rviz new Qt dependency would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, this is a bit tricky, because EmPy is what the name of library is in pip, but when you use it in python you have to `import em`.  This makes trouble when defining it as a dependency in Homebrew.

There is a way around this, but it hasn't found its way into the repo yet.  One way around it is to edit `/usr/local/Library/Taps/ros-fuerte/catkin.rb` and comment out the line `depends_on 'EmPy' => :python`.  Then catkin should install.  You are likely to run into more problems though, as this is still sort of experimental.

Sorry I don't have a better answer, all I can say is that we are working on it as we find time.  If you are looking to get work done, I recommend Electric for the time being.  If you are just interested in Fuerte then we always appreciate some help.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1